Dead GPU after this thing got unstuck
I was trying to open and clean GPU and this happened so is it important thing?


The little browninsh component is a ceramic capacitor. Without more context it's impossible to say for sure that this is the cause. But from experience I'd say that this is probably not the reason that your GPU doesn't work anymore.

Cleaning it doesn't sound relevant. Did you have a compelling reason to clean your circuit board?

@kruemi So i connected everything again and it works fine so should i bring it somewhere to repair it?

It might be possible to solder it back if it was torn off cleanly. If the part is damaged, it will be impossible to determine what capacitor it is. At least nobody knows how important it is or not.

I wanted to clean and replace the thermal pads but it still works fine it seems

Your question title implies that your GPU does not work anymore ("Dead GPU"). That is a bit misleading.

The component that is "unstuck" is almost certainly a ceramic capacitor.
Its role within the whole system is impossible to assess from the picture, most probably even with a bigger picture it would require a lot of work to understand whether it is important or not.
That said, it is not unsurprising that the board works - if it is a decoupling cap, odds are it is not necessary in all situations, and it appears to still be making contact to some extent.
I would resolder it myself, but I suspect you lack both the tools and the skills necessary - bring it to a repair shop and they should be able to take care of this in a minute, and I would be very surprised if they charged you anything. I suggest you call in advance and explain on the phone that "a 0402 or 0603 capacitor got partially desoldered and needs to be resoldered". 0402 is read like a phone number, 'oh-four-oh-two' and similarly for 0603.
Definitely take the time to have it fixed, if nothing else for peace of mind.
